# use LIKE for 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I need to search in the `hostel` table .

structure:

```
CREATE TABLE hostel( 
p_id VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
hostel VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY(p_id));
```

I have inserted searched word in `$word`

```
select * from hostel where hostel like '%$word%'
```

Will below query work? I need to search in both "hostel" and "address" column

```
select * from hostel where hostel like '%$word%' AND address like '%$word%'
```

Comment: Why don't you just test it?

Comment: It depends on what you want. Your query will result only hostels, where hostel and address have the text $word in it. I think what you want is to change the AND to an OR, so it returns rows, when either hostel or address contains $word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from hostel where hostel like '%$word%' OR address like '%$word%'
```

will bring better results

Answer (score 1):

```
Better change those searchable fields(hostel,address) to full text which will fasten the search

SELECT MATCH('Content') AGAINST ('keyword1
keyword2') as Relevance FROM table 

select match($word) against (hostel,address)  as Relevance FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

This works without a problem

```
select * from hostel where hostel like '%$word%' AND address like '%$word%'
```